# C++ error received

Tags: c++

I have this code:
i receive next error: A::A(int) candidate expect 1 argument, 0 provided but I cannot understand what the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
    int x;
    public:
    A(int i):x(i) {}
    int get_x() const {return x;}
};

class B:public A
{
    int *y;
    public:
    B(int i):A(i) {y=new int[i]; for(int j=0;j<i;j++) y[j]=1;}
B(B&);
    int &operator[] (int i) {return y[i];}
};

B::B(B&a)
{
    y=new int[a.get_x()];
    for(int i=0;i<a.get_x();i++) y[i]=a[i];
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, B a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<a.get_x();i++) o<<a[i];
    return o;
}
int main()
{
    B b(5);
    cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your second `B` constructor you don't call the correct `A` constructor.

Comment: ok, but why not ?

Comment: `B::B(B &a) : A(a.get_x()){ ...` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your second `B` constructor `B::B(B&a)` implicitly tries to construct the base class `A` using its default constructor, which is not defined.

You may explicitly call the `A(int)` constructor, i.e.:

```
B::B(B&a)
: A(a.get_x())
{
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `A` does not have a constructor that takes 0 arguments you need to explicitly call the constructor with arguments provided from any class constructor that inherits from `A`, which is `B` in this case.

In your first constructor:

```
B(int i):A(i) {y=new int[i]; for(int j=0;j<i;j++) y[j]=1;}
```

You are doing this well by calling `A(i)`.

But in your second constructor:

```
B::B(B&a)
{
y=new int[a.get_x()];
for(int i=0;i<a.get_x();i++) y[i]=a[i];
}
```

There is no call to `A`'s constructor and thus you get an error since the compiler doesn't know how to create an `A` object, you probably meant to do :

```
B::B(B&a) : A(a.get_x())
{
y=new int[a.get_x()];
for(int i=0;i<a.get_x();i++) y[i]=a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that **when you declare an object of type `B` you also sort need to construct an instance of `A`**. 
In  `B::B(B&a)` you do not explicitly call any constructor for `A`, so the compiler try to call the one with no parameters `A::A()`, but it fails since it is not declared.

You  have to either declare a `A::A()` in `A` or explicitly call one of the available constructors in `A` from `B`'s constructror.

---

Note that `A::A()` could be automatically generated by the compiler, and is called default constructor. Read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)